# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' Python3

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

*This is a voice assitance and i want hear my voice and open google or searching! but My program has a AttributeError*

I want :

1.initialization
2.speak
3.hear and speech Recognization
4.Do Something Like searching

**My Code**:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import jdatetime
import persian

Boss = 'Mohamaad'
print('Hello sir %s' % Boss)
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

speak('Hello sir %s' % Boss)

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.record(source,duration=2)
        speak('I am Listening sir')
        print("Listening ....")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try :
         print("Recognizing...")
         query = r.recognize_google(audio, Language ='en-us')
         print(f"user said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again please")
        speak('Say that again please')
        query=None

    return query

wishMe()
query = takeCommand()



#Logic for executing tasks as per the query
if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
    speak('searching in wikipedia....')
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
    print(results)
    speak(results)

elif 'open youtube' in query.lower():
    url = 'youtube.com'
    chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application/chrome.exe %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
elif 'open Google' in query.lower():
    url = 'Google.com'
    chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application/chrome.exe %'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
elif 'open github' in query.lower():
    url = 'github.com'
    chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application/chrome.exe %'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
elif 'Play music' in query.lower():
    songs_dir = "C:\\Users\\mohmmad\\Downloads\\Music"
    songs = os.listdir(songs_dir)
    speak(songs)
    os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir,songs[0]))

elif 'time' in query():
    strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    speak(f"{Boss} the time is {strTime}")
```

**Output:**

Initializing Jarvis, haa haa haa!!
Hello sir Mohamaad 
2020-06-16 18:21:58.364205 
1399-03-27 18:21:58.370148 
Listening .... 
Recognizing... 
Say that again please 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Us`enter code here`ers\mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Prject man\Main.py", line 71, in 
    if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

thanks for your helping

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! An `AttributeError: 'NoneType'` in python is an error meaning that you have tried to access a variable that has been set to `None`, meaning that it is empty or has no value or in other programming languages is null. I recommend going back through your code and figuring out what situations could cause `query` to be `None` and then modify your code to handle those situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the query is not None

```
if query:
    if 'wikipedia' in query.lower():
        speak('searching in wikipedia....')
        query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences =2)
        print(results)
        speak(results)

    elif 'open youtube' in query.lower():
        url = 'youtube.com'
        chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application/chrome.exe %s'
        webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

The error that in the header is because you are trying to `lower()` None type object and from your code it seems that it's happened in the query value.