# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'. for django-comments-dab app

Tags: python, django

I want to use django-comments-dab but I meet this Error,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/2020/9/6/test4
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
Exception Location: D:\amirblog\venv\lib\site-packages\comment\utils.py, line 26, in get_model_obj
Python Executable:  D:\amirblog\venv\Scripts\python.exe

utils.py

```
def get_model_obj(app_name, model_name, model_id):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_name, model=model_name.lower())
    model_object = content_type.get_object_for_this_type(id=model_id)

    return model_object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407341/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-lower-python3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model_name` is `None` and not a string. Only strings have the `lower` method defined for them. Try `print(model_name)` and `print(type(model_name))` to see that this is the case, and then fix whatever is calling `get_model_obj` to pass in a string.

Comment: Yes bro youre right, I did print and the result was None and NoneType , how can I fix it? :(

Comment: If you don't want to specify `model_name` you could call `get_model_obj` with `model_name=''`. Then `''.lower()` will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed mine now the `{% render comment obj request %}` should not be so only if you are using a class view should and what you are passing to the context is obj that's when it should be `{% render comment obj request%}` but if just change it to whatever you passed in your context did it and it work fined for me like this:

```
{% comment %} call comment app tags {% endcomment %}
{% render_comments post request %}
```